# Android: Key aspectX expected Integer but value was a java.lang.Double. The default value 0 was returned

Tags: android, image, crop

I got the below exception sort while working with Images in android, any solutions for this.

Key aspectX expected Integer but value was a java.lang.Double.  The default value 0 was returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the exception is very self explanatory: you are giving as number of the type Double and what it needs is an Integer.

If this doesn't ring any bell:

```
Double: 1.2, 2.9, 3.4 .... etc!
Integer: 1, 2, 100, 320 .... etc!
```

which means that your code must look like:

```
i.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
```

and not like:

```
i.putExtra("aspectX", 1.1);
```

Just print the variable or parameter you are passing before use it with:

```
Log.e ("My AspectX var is:", ""+my_aspectX_var);
```

and see what type of value it is.